# Data is not rendering on home page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I migrate jQuery 1.8.2 to 3.1.1. Suceesfully migrate in my solution but i faced UI issue on my home page. Span tag show on home page.

For UI i added jquery-ui-1.12.1.js & jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js.

```
<div class="class  name">
           &lt;span class="MD Class"&gt;Medical Centre&lt;/span&gt;
 </div>
```

Here i was stuck last few days. I unable to found what is issue.

Below I showed image :

This html showed on home page.

[image]

Comment: Change  `&lt;span class="MD class"&gt;Medical Assitance&lt;/span&gt;` to `<span class="MD class">Medical Assistance</span>`

Comment: If you copy as text that same as you sugeested html . Here i copy as element at runtime generated html.